# Neo4j APOC verify trigger already exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I use Neo4j APOC in order to install the following trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_ADD_TO_INDEX', 'UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) RETURN count(*)', {phase:'after'})
```

Also, I use the following in order to remove the trigger:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.remove('HAS_VALUE_ON_ADD_TO_INDEX') yield name, installed
```

I don't want to try to install/remove this trigger when it already exists/doesn't exist.

I'd be really grateful if you can show me the way how I can check the trigger existence with APOC.. probably some Boolean functions (or something like that) that can be used in order to verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There the `apoc.trigger.list` procedure for that :

```
CALL apoc.trigger.list() yield name
WHERE name ='HAS_VALUE_ON_ADD_TO_INDEX'
RETURN name
```